# Android, can't add more elements with IDs, InflateException

Tags: android

I have a fragment xml containing a View at the bottom:

```
   <View
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   />
```

The app starts just fine.
I now add an ID to this view:

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/myTestId"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   />
```

Without making any further modifications to the code, the app crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package, PID: 17505
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package/com.package.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56 in com.package:layout/main_panel: Binary XML file line #56 in com.package:layout/main_panel: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56 in com.package:layout/main_panel: Binary XML file line #56 in com.package:layout/main_panel: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56 in com.package:layout/main_panel: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.package.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:167)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarItemView.<init>(NavigationBarItemView.java:97)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:34)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.createNavigationBarItemView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:197)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView.getNewItem(NavigationBarMenuView.java:492)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView.buildMenuView(NavigationBarMenuView.java:421)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationBarPresenter.java:72)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.inflateMenu(NavigationBarView.java:358)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.<init>(NavigationBarView.java:226)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:103)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:98)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:93)
        ... 31 more
```

The line number specified in this stacktrace is simply the beginning of this BottomNavigationView:

```
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/btm_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/colorOnBackGround"
        app:itemIconTint="?attr/colorOnBackGround"
        android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundElevated"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_bottom"/>
```

This file is in no way related to the fragment xml mentioned at the top, where i added an ID. In fact, no matter in which XML file I add elements, as soon as I add an ID to the element (no matter what id, i tried multiple) my app crashes with this weird bug. Its as if i have reached some kind of limit to using IDs. Ive worked on this app for 2 years and never ran into a similar bug.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please share the complete XML file

Comment: Try running ``Clean`` and then ``Rebuild`` in the Build menu, and possibly ``Invalidate Caches and Restart`` under File. It's a good place to start if weird stuff with IDs starts happening

Comment: Running Clean build fixed it, but i tried adding more elements, and for every additional element it initially crashes, until i manually clean build.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs) advice in the comment and did a `Clean Build` this made the app run again, however for every additional element i add, i now need to run `Clean build`, otherwise it will crash with the stack trace above.